# Calculations of NTFS Partition Table Starting Points

Tags: ntfs, fat, computer-forensics, ntfs-mft

I have a disk image. I'm able to see partition start and end values with gparted or another tools. However, I want to calculate them manually. I inserted an image , which showing my disk image partition start and end values. Also, I inserted $MFT file with link. As you see in the picture, my starter point for partition table 2 is : 7968240. How can I determine this number with real calculation ? I tried to dived this value with sector size which is 512. However, results are not fit. I'll appriciate for a formula for it. Start and End Points of Partitions.

[image: Image of Partition Starting Points]

$MFT File : https://file.io/r7sy2A7itdur

How can I determine this number with real calculation ?

Answer (score 0):

The information about how a hard disk has been partitioned is stored in its first sector (that is, the first sector of the first track on the first disk surface). The first sector is the master boot record (**MBR**) of the disk; this is the sector that the BIOS reads in and starts when the machine is first booted.

For the current partition system (**gpt**) you can get more [information here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table). The MFT is only a part on the NTFS in question, which is calculated via GPT or MBR.